# Unable to access model in plugin

Tags: cakephp

I have two Plugins in cakephp both contains User model. When I want to access the properties of User model it always call first User model. How can I access second User Model?

Comment: Two user models as in two classes with the same name? That is not possible in Cake2.x. You need to be a little bit more creative regarding your class naming.

Comment: You have to specify the plugin name when you initialize the model classes from them. So you could call your first one 'User' and your second one 'PluginUser', ie `$this->User = ClassRegistry::init('PluginOne.User');` and `$this->PluginTwoUser = ClassRegistry::init('PluginTwo.User');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not possible - rename your models

Unfortunately that's not possible. Because of the way models are defined, that means you're wanting to load two different classes with the same name in the same namespace (global) which is not possible with PHP - the only solution is to use different classnames.

A standard practice is to name plugin classes prefixed with the plugin name to avoid collisions:

So for example in the foo plugin:

```
<?php
//App/Plugin/Foo/Model/FooUser.php
class FooUser extends FooAppModel {
}
```

And in the bar plugin:

```
<?php
//App/Plugin/Bar/Model/BarUser.php
class BarUser extends BarAppModel {
}
```

This does lead to slightly more cumbersome usage, but prevents roadblock-problems when trying to access both classes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the plugin name when you initialize the model classes. So you could call your first one 'User' and your second one 'PluginUser', ie:

```
$this->User = ClassRegistry::init('PluginOne.User');
$this->PluginUser = ClassRegistry::init('PluginTwo.User');
```